# MVC5 With EF6 AS DAL

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

i have worked with [pre EF 5 releases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574253.aspx) and then there was only an `.edmx` file. With EF6 when i add the `DataModel` and give the path of already existing databse there a lot of files generated with `.tt` extension. Can anybody guide me to

what is the actual purpose of [`T4`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx) templates

how can i mange the update of relational model in EF6 and the mapping of POCO to `ViewModels`

what is EF 6.x DbContext Generator

Im confused a bit please help to calrify a bit just nedd a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I should be answering this question having probably not much more (if any more) experience with EF and MVC than you. But my understanding is that the use of TT scripts allows you to have more control about how the code is generated from the model. In my opinion, having the model *and* the TT scripts *and* the generated code all in your project seems like a lot of messy overhead, which is why I have taken to using the code first paradigm instead. As a coder, I find this to be ideal. I write classes to represent the model I want, and EF automatically (for the most part) derives a database structure from that, and even automatically creates the database if it does not exist. It's quite remarkable, with so little code and so few extra files to maintain.

Comment: tnx for your time, since long i have been away from ,net stuff and suddenly i have found myself in the middle of a project including all this new shiny stuff and i guess im panicking :) ... guess have to hit the drawing boards again ...Regards

Comment: I am in a similar situation. I haven't been away from .NET, but I've been away from web development and never learned EF (I learned LINQ-to-SQL, which is simialr, though). There's a lot to catch up on, but you just prototype some simple example projects to demonstrate to yourself that you're understanding the new technologies, and in a couple weeks you'll be feeling a bit more comfortable, but still have a long way to go before feeling expert.